# how to run a function after html value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing a simple hover scrollbar project. I want to change the height of thumb when someone change the contents in html tag by `prepend(),append(),html()`..etc. how can I do this? I googled it and found answers like

```
$('.class').html('value').trigger(somefunction())
```

But it is not the answer. Because I am not the developer of other js codes. I want to do this with only my script file.

here is my project :-
https://github.com/rameshkithsiri/hoverscroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is way of doing so , you can use `DOMSubtreeModified` events. But look out [It before using it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified)

```js
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', ".myCLASS", function() {
   alert($(this).html());
});
setTimeout(function(){ $(".myCLASS").html("my Test") }, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="myCLASS"></div>
```